# S проверить разрешены ли push-уведомления от сайта

Tags: javascript, html, push

Как сделать так, что бы если разрешены уведомления от сайта, то выполнить один скрипт, а если запрещены, то другой.
Надеюсь я выбрал правильную категорию для вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю как-то так:

```js
if (Notification.permission === 'denied')
{
    console.log('уведомления заблокированы');
}
else
{
    console.log('уведомления разрешены');
}
```